# Android GPS unable to get my location

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-location, android-gps

I have an app that used to work fine as of 2 weeks ago. Today I ran the code and running into some issues. It doesn't seem to be able to detect that my gps (location option) is on startup. When the location is off, I will pop up a message on startup and asked to turn on the location option, after I turned it on, it will show my current location. However, if I exit the application, and reopen it again, it doesn't show my current location even though the location options is still on.

Again, it used to work, I was always able to get my current location on startup, but I don't know why it doesn't work anymore as I didn't change anything.

The Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider) is always returning null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = fm.getMap();

    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 90);
    //loadSettings();
    // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        //Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            changeLocation(point);
        }
    });
    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);



private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        }
                    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there was an update in the google-services repository maybe you could check that